# linq to xml - remove wrapper node

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

is there a way to remove a node that is wrapping a few other nodes, but keeping the containing nodes?

I need to remove all the instances of "AreaImageCaption", but need to keep "image" and "caption"

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>100</name>
        <AreaImageCaption>
            <image>image1</image>
            <caption>caption1</caption>
        </AreaImageCaption>
        <AreaImageCaption>
            <image>image2</image>
            <caption>caption2</caption>
        </AreaImageCaption>
    </product>
</products>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        string s =
            @"<products>
        <product>
            <name>100</name>
            <AreaImageCaption>
                <image>image1</image>
                <caption>caption1</caption>
            </AreaImageCaption>
            <AreaImageCaption>
                <image>image2</image>
                <caption>caption2</caption>
            </AreaImageCaption>
       </product>
    </products>";

        XElement element = XElement.Parse(s);
        element.Descendants("AreaImageCaption").ToList().ForEach(aic =>
                                                                 {
                                                                     aic.Elements().ToList().ForEach(el => aic.Parent.Add(el));
                                                                     aic.Remove();
                                                                 });

        string result = element.ToString();
```

I'm trying to add all child elements from `<AreaImageCaption />` and add it to it's parent and then remove the `<AreaImageCaption />` element.

Comment: that seems to work. The only issue with it is that the original XML file has more nodes after AreaImageCaption, and with this approach all the image and caption nodes will be attached to the end of the XML file, and need them to stay in the same position... any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to keep the order. Probably not the right thing to do but can't you just replace `<AreaImageCaption>` and `</AreaImageCaption>` with string.Empty ?

Comment: yeah that was the first thing I thought about but it doesn't look like the most elegant approach... I thought there might be some other way

Comment: you can either insert at the the end as shown above or at the beginning with `AddFirst()`. There is also `AddAfterSelf()` which I have never used. See if it is what you need.